# UDP client to listen to a multicast group/port without setting its own IP?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, tcp, udp

I have a small microcontroller device that I program via USB using Python. The device has an Ethernet connection, which can be configured either with DHCP or by manually setting the IP/Subnet via USB. The device is connected to my local LAN using a very simple unmanaged switch.

My understanding is that in order for UDP multicast to work, the device needs to have its IP set, even though it's simply listening to a multicast group/port. This may seem counterintuitive.

Is there a way for UDP clients to listen to a multicast group/port without setting their own IP?

Or alternatively, is there a way to communicate with the device via Ethernet before its IP is set?

Comment: Where did you see that UDP multicast requires an IP ?

Comment: My device is based on an RP2040 which runs Python (Micropython) on bare metal, so no OS. Micropython just deals with the Ethernet controller drivers directly. Your point is still valid though. One could use sockets directly without relying on network interfaces I guess.

Comment: @harrymc most examples I've seen which don't rely on DHCP require the client to setup its IP manually in the same subnet as the server. Not sure if there is a way to set up the client in the server's subnet without setting the whole IP.

Comment: For multicast, it's good enough to be on the same physical network via your simple switch, and you shouldn't technically need an IP. Smarter switches/routers generally don't extend broadcast traffic to other subnets, so it's good to have client and server in the same one when possible

Comment: @Cpt.Whale So if I understand this correctly, if I just run something like 'tcpdump udp port 3000' in a laptop connected to my switch, I should be able to receive a multicast in my network?

Comment: @Miki I believe you have to tell it what interface to use for broadcast traffic like `tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp`. You might also have to specify `ether broadcast or ether multicast`, but I'm pretty sure that's just for filtering out.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale What about the other end (sender)? 'echo "hi" | nc -u -w0 192.168.2.2 3000' only works for me when I provide an IP that matches the IP of the receiver (192.168.2.2). Can I use nc to test this when the receiver has no IP?

Comment: Use the actual multicast address like: `echo -n 1234567890| ncat -vu 224.4.4.4 4444`. https://serverfault.com/a/1062886/411612

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I was able to send/receive UDP multicast packets between my two laptops. On the sender side: `echo -n 1234567890 | nc -s 192.168.2.1 -p 3000 -vu 224.4.4.4 -w0 3000`. For the receiver end: `sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 host 224.4.4.4`. However, the receiver's network connection had to be set up as IPv4/link-local only, which, by default, assigns an IP in the range of `169.254.0.0` to `169.254.255.255` and creates a new interface, enp2s0, which is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: At that point, it's probably down to the drivers/micropython itself requiring an IP (which I know nothing about). Does it work if you assign it a random ipv6 address? `enp2s0` is a newer-style systemd/udev "predictable" name https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/. Those can usually be disabled or customized.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I have two laptops and my device all in the same LAN. I am able to send/receive between the laptops as explained above, but no luck configuring the device. I'm looking into its micropython build/drivers and they require either [ip, subnet, gateway, dns] or DHCP. Seems another dead end. The manufacture swears their chip supports UDP multicast, but seems the drivers/micropython are not up to the task.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Following up on "Does it work if you assign it a random ipv6 address?", I am going to try to implement a simple Multicast DNS, where the IP assigned to the device is derived from its mac address. The real issue here is how do I communicate from a server to n devices I connect to the same LAN and configure them all remotely (no DHCP). Maybe mDNS is all I need.

Answer (score -1):

Multicast is a broadcast protocol that doesn't need a destination
IP address, only a port number, and it is delivered to all computers.

Multicasting will send an identical message to every member of a group.
A group is identified by a multicast address.
A multicast address must use the following IP address range:
`224.0.0.0` through `239.255.255.255`.
The server will send a message marked with this address and clients
must join the group before they can receive any multicast messages.
This address itself is not a valid IP that can normally be used by
any one computer and is only used as a tag to identify the group.

You can see an example of a client program in
[Simple listener.c program for UDP multicast](https://gist.github.com/hostilefork/f7cae3dc33e7416f2dd25a402857b6c6).

Comment: Why the downvote  ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would send/receive UDP packets, maybe using python or netcat/tcpdump or similar? Can you also describe the local network configuration required?

Comment: Programming is rather for StackOverflow. I'm just saying here that for receiving multicast all you need is the right socket, as you can well see in the example program. Even the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP call in the example only tells the switch/router that there is a listener for that group on this interface (some switches will not multicast to interfaces without listeners).